# To send an image with size 10kb for every 100 ms., should I use TCP or UDP?

Tags: udp, tcp

a single block of secret information in 10 consecutive images of size 10 Kbytes generated every 100 ms. In order for Hermes to operate normally, all 10 images should be received within 5 seconds.

Comment: You haven't given us any of the information needed to decide whether TCP or UDP is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TCP:

- You need to receive all 10 images, which is 100K in size.  This will not fit in a single IPv4 UDP datagram, so using UDP means you will have to send and keep track of at least 2 datagrams.  Most source recommend much small UDP packets, so that means reassembling many smaller packets.  This is not necessary in TCP.
- With UDP, you will need to take care of sending acknowledgements and retransmitting one or more datagrams if the acknowledgement is not received.  TCP takes care of this for you.

If your application cannot tolerate data loss, it is almost always better to start with TCP.